# different button images in different CSS files

Tags: image, button

My job is to combine different CSS files in a single HTML using buttons. So the CSS design changes every time you click a button.
I solved the task by adding and removing every CSS with JavaScript.
My problem: I want different images in the buttons for each page, but so far I only have the images in the HTML in the buttons.

Javasprict:

```
 let body = document.body;

 let actionBtn = document.getElementById('action');
 let loveBtn = document.getElementById('love');
 let cartoonBtn = document.getElementById('cartoon');
 let animeBtn = document.getElementById('anime');
 let childrenBtn = document.getElementById('children');

 actionBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 body.classList.remove('love','cartoon','anime');
 body.classList.add('action');
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="button">
 <button id="action"><img src="action.png" alt="Actionfilm-Bild"></button>
 <button id="love"><img src="love.png" alt="Liebesfilm-Bild"></button>
 <button id="cartoon"><img src="cartoon.png" alt="Cartoon-Bild"></button>
 <button id="anime"><img src="anime.png" alt="Anime-Bild"></button>
```

Comment: I think some more information is required to help you. If you just want to change the src of your image, you can just give each `<img>` tag an id and use `document.getElementById("imageid").src = "newimage.png` but I am not even sure that's what you want.

Comment: I've posted it in more detail now. I hope it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you do have to do exactly what I commented but I will answer here to show you exactly what I mean. You will only need to add something to your javascript file and an id for each image.

HTML:

```
<button id="action"><img id="actionBtnImage src="action.png" alt="Actionfilm-Bild"></button>
```

```
let body = document.body;

let actionBtn = document.getElementById('action');
let actionBtnImage = document.getElementById('actionBtnImage');

actionBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
       body.classList.remove('love','cartoon','anime','children','western','scary','fantasy','quiet','nature');
       body.classList.add('action');
       actionBtnImage.src="newimage.png";    //Do this for each button image you want to change
});
```

That's of course just one button but I think you should be able to do the others for yourself!

Comment: Thank you so much. That make sense. But now something doesnt work. I will post my Java and HTML, maybe you know whats going on. I will edit my last post.

Comment: @Sarah I wouldn't recommened editing your post, because it will probably completly change the topic of the question and isn't really what you want to do on StackOverflow. You can edit your question and just append the new question at the end but why don't you just look up your new problem,.StackOverflow isn't really here to guide you through your whole project and I certainly don't have the time to do so either.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not know that. For the next time I will know that. Thank you again for the approach.

Answer (score 0):

[this is what happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he8Ta.jpg)

```js
     let actionBtn = document.getElementById('action');
     let actionBtnImage = document.getElementById('actionBtnImage');
     let loveBtn = document.getElementById('love');
     let cartoonBtn = document.getElementById('cartoon');
     let animeBtn = document.getElementById('anime');
     let childrenBtn = document.getElementById('children');
     let westernBtn = document.getElementById('western');
     let scaryBtn = document.getElementById('scary');
     let fantasyBtn = document.getElementById('fantasy');
     let quietBtn = document.getElementById('quiet');
     let natureBtn = document.getElementById('nature');

     actionBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
       body.classList.remove('love','cartoon','anime','children','western','scary','fantasy','quiet','nature');
       body.classList.add('action');
       actionBtnImage.src="action.png";
       loveBtnImage.src="love.png";
       cartoonBtnImage.src="cartoon.png";
       animeBtnImage.src="anime.png";
       childrenBtn.src="children.png";
       westernBtn.src="scary.png";
       fantasyBtn.src="fantasy.png";
       quietBtn.src="quiet.png";
       natureBtn.src="nature.png";
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sarah Schönfelder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="action.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="love.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cartoon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="anime.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="children.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="western.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scary.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fantasy.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nature.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="all.css">
  </head>

  <header>
   <nav>
    <div class="button">
      <button id="action"><img id="actionBtnImage" alt="Actionfilm-Bild"></button>
      <button id="love"><img id="loveBtnImage" alt="Liebesfilm-Bild"></button>
      <button id="cartoon"><img id="cartoonBtnImage" alt="Cartoon-Bild"></button>
      <button id="anime"><img id="animeBtnImage" alt="Anime-Bild"></button>
      <button id="children"><img id="childrenBtnImage" alt="Kinderfilm-Bild"></button>
      <button id="western"><img id="westernBtnImage" alt="Westernfilm-Bild"></button>
      <button id="scary"><img id="scaryBtnImage" alt="Horrorfilm-Bild"></button>
      <button id="fantasy"><img id="fantasyBtnImage" alt="Fantasyfilm-Bild"></button>
      <button id="quiet"><img id="quietBtnImage" alt="Stummfilm-Bild"></button>
      <button id="nature"><img id="natureBtnImage" alt="Doku-Bild"></button>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only thing I can find here is that you removed this line `let body = document.body;` not sure why or if you just forgot it here but that's the error I get here.